# How to find the closest dates from MySQL table based on results of another SELECT statement

Tags: mysql, select

I am trying to find if there is a faster way to get the following result -

- table1 contains  id, event_date, (some other columns not relevant here)
- table2 contains  id, calender_date, my_value, (some other columns not relevant here)

I want to write a query that selects all ids and event_dates from table1 and for each event_date find the closest calendar_date from table2 such that calendar_date is at least 30 days before the event_date. Lastly, I want the my_value corresponding to the calendar_date that satifies this criteria.

I hope it is clear that the reason I am doing this is because (event_date - 30 days) might not exist in table2 so it should return the closest available date.

Here is what I have done so far. The query works as expected but I want to know if this is the fastest way possible to do this.

```
    SELECT t2.id, events.event_date, MAX(t2.calendar_date) AS closest_date FROM table2 AS t2,
    (SELECT t1.id, t1.event_date FROM table1 AS t1) AS events
    WHERE t2.id=events.id 
    AND t2.calendar_date BETWEEN DATE_SUB(events.event_date, INTERVAL 40 DAY) AND DATE_SUB(events.event_date, INTERVAL 30 DAY) 
    GROUP BY events.id, events.event_date;
```

Thanks for all the help.